# Reverse Linked List recursively, should the last node point to null?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to understand the recursive way to Reverse Linked List.

```
    public ListNode reverseList2(ListNode head) {

        if(head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }

        ListNode newHead = reverseList2(head.next);
        head.next.next = head;
        head.next = null;

        return newHead;

    }
```

reverse linked list

```
1->2->3->null
```

the answer will be

```
3->2->1->null
```

From my understanding, the last node should point to null. But in this recursive function, when it reverses the last node, it didn't point it to null. Is that be ok, the last node not point to null? or do I missing something?

Comment: Your understanding shown in the examples is correct. The new tail (old head) should point to null.

Answer (score 1):

You're example works. However, it doesn't work when you remove the line `head.next = null;`

```
public ListNode reverseList2(ListNode head) {

    if(head == null || head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }

    ListNode newHead = reverseList2(head.next);
    head.next.next = head;

    return newHead;

}
```

where it becomes a circular linked list where the tail points back to the head. You might of accidentally forgot about that line, and then the tail didn't point to null. This is  because that line ensures that if you're at the end, the next is equal to null.